# Query taking long time to execute in different database instance

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

My application is used with different database instances. A particular query is executing in 1 second in all database instances except for one where it is taking more than 30 minutes. What can be the reason? Although data volume is almost the same. My Database is Oracle 11g.

Here is the query

```
SELECT b.VC_CUSTOMER_NAME customer,
       TO_CHAR( sum(c.INV_VALUE), '999,999,999,999') value,
       ROUND(
         (SUM (c.inv_value) / (SELECT SUM (c.inv_value) 
                               FROM   mks_mst_customer b,
                                      sls_temp_invoice_ticket c,
                                      sls_dt_invoice_ticket d 
                               WHERE  c.vc_comp_code = b.vc_comp_code
                               AND    b.vc_comp_code = '01'
                               AND    INV_LABEL LIKE 'COLLECT FROM CUSTOMER%' 
                               AND    d.vc_ticket_no=c.vc_ticket_no
                               AND    d.dt_invoice_date BETWEEN '01-Dec-2021' AND '07-Dec-2021'
                               AND    b.nu_account_code=c.nu_account_code)
         )* 100
       ) PERCENT
FROM   mks_mst_customer b,
       sls_temp_invoice_ticket c,
       sls_dt_invoice_ticket d 
WHERE  c.vc_comp_code = b.vc_comp_code
AND    b.vc_comp_code = '01' 
AND    INV_LABEL like 'COLLECT FROM CUSTOMER%'
AND    b.nu_account_code=c.nu_account_code 
AND    d.vc_ticket_no=c.vc_ticket_no
AND    d.dt_invoice_date BETWEEN '01-Dec-2021' AND '07-Dec-2021'
GROUP BY b.VC_CUSTOMER_NAME
ORDER BY SUM(c.INV_VALUE) DESC
```

Comment: don't use dates as string ('01-Dec-2021'), always use to_date with format or date function (to_date('01-Dec-2021', 'DD-Mon-YYYY'))). Databases can have different date formats in it could work on one, and fail on the other. This doesn't of course solve your issue.

Comment: @OracleDev That's a good idea, but to be even safer you might want to use ANSI literals like `date '2021-12-01'`. A date literal won't depend on any client settings, like a language that might not work with 'Dec'.

Comment: @JonHeller thats what I meant with "date function" but didn't write a sample. Thanks for doing that.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious step would be to check indexes, on this slow instance they might not be configured.

Little more demanding would be to get [statistics](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/text.101/b10729/aoptim.htm)

Comment: I have not done anything. Today I ran the query again and it was executed in 1 second. Now I am not getting how it was automatically solved.

Comment: The misteries of SQL ;). Maybe some process was using this database causing it to execute slowly